# SQL скрипт( оставить только цифры в строке)

Tags: java, sql

Есть такой столбик, в нем написано "Виконання 532", как написать скрипт чтобы когда я его запущу в этой строке остались только 532, таких строк очень много и в ручную это займет пару дней

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 1):

- С использованием основных функций работы со строками `RIGHT`, `LEN` и оператора `LIKE` для поиска строк с префиксом

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET search_number_contract = RIGHT(
    search_number_contract, 
    LEN(search_number_contract) - LEN('Виконання даних ')
)
WHERE search_number_contract LIKE 'Виконання даних %'
```

(Аналогично можно использовать `SUBSTRING`)

- С использованием функции `REPLACE` (если формат содержимого определен как `$строка_префикс$число`):

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET search_number_contract = REPLACE(
    search_number_contract, 'Виконання даних ', ''
)
WHERE search_number_contract LIKE 'Виконання даних %'
```

- С использованием регулярных выражений, но этот функционал отличается для разных СУБД.

Во всех показанных случаях использование Java необязательно, достаточно SQL-запроса `UPDATE`.